# Why does my JFrame not update

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

I have this piece of code of a JFrame that will show the user the progress during the importing time of images:

```
public class LoadFrame implements Runnable {

    JProgressBar progressbar;
    JPanel loadpanel;
    MainScreen mainscreen;
    int progress;
    JDialog mainloadframe;

    public LoadFrame(String operation) {

        mainloadframe = new JDialog();
        JLabel operationlabel = new JLabel(operation);
        progressbar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        loadpanel = new JPanel();

        mainloadframe.setSize(300, 75);
        mainloadframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainloadframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        mainloadframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        mainloadframe.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        mainloadframe.setTitle(operation);
        mainloadframe.setVisible(true);

        progressbar.setValue(0);
        progressbar.setStringPainted(true);
        loadpanel.add(progressbar);
        loadpanel.add(operationlabel);
        mainloadframe.add(loadpanel);

    }

    public void setMainScreen(MainScreen mainscreen) {
        this.mainscreen = mainscreen;
    }

    public void disposeLoadFrame() {
        mainloadframe.dispose();
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (progress != 100) {
            progressbar.setValue(progress);
        }
    }
}
```

the actual calculating of the progress is also done in an thread, but for some reason the progressbar doesn't show up on the JFrame till the moment the images are done importing. I'm pretty sure it is a Thread problem but I can't seem to figure it out. A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: UI updates have to happen on the EDT. Doing that from any other thread is undefined behaviour and causes anything from erratic drawing, wrong controls popping up all over the place, working correctly to not working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Runnable#Thread` isn't `start()`
- (post to the forums) have to add `Thread.sleep(int)` into `run()`, then `progressbar.setValue(progress);` mest be wrapped into `invokeLater()`
- by using util.Timer instead of Runnable#Thread , then `progressbar.setValue(progress);` mest be wrapped into `invokeLater()`

---

- by using `Swing Timer`

---

- proper of ways is invoke `progressbar.setValue(progress);` from `SwingWorker`